# is three js Object3D.matrixWorldAutoUpdate properties exist?

Tags: three.js, aframe

While checking three js apis, Object3D.matrixWorldAutoUpdate properties exists in the documentaion [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.matrixWorldAutoUpdate), which says:
.matrixWorldAutoUpdate : Boolean
Default is true. If set, then the renderer checks every frame if the object and its children need matrix updates. When it isn't, then you have to maintain all matrices in the object and its children yourself.

But when I try this in aframe 1.3.0 environment, I found no matrixWorldAutoUpdate properties in my Object3D, I import aframe like

```
 <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

make object3d like:

```
 var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color:0x0000ff,
  // wireframe:true,
});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.translateY(1);
    
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    group.translateY(-1.33);
   
    group.add(mesh);
    
    scene.add(group);
```

both mesh and group object dont have matrixWorldAutoUpdate properties.

Question:
1.is Aframe using specific version of three js rather than three js master or realse tags? if so, how do I check the version of three js that Aframe building from? How could I check the original three js source code?
2.what's the design purpose or usage example of matrixWorldAutoUpdate properties? if it's false, it means matrixworld is not calculated from its position/rotation/scale? and we could set it's matrixworld directly? ignoring the local matrix properties?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A-Frame is using a forked version of three.js called [super-three](https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-three).

**Basically from what I can tell the super-three version tells you the three.js version.**
The version of super-three being used in A-Frame tag 1.3.0 is `^0.137.0` and can be found in the [package.json](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.3.0/package.json). This version of super-three uses release [r137](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermedium/three.js/r137/build/three.js) of Three.js.

You can check the source code of the [three.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermedium/three.js/r137/build/three.js) being used by super-three. It's likely that they haven't rebased the fork to a recent version of three that includes `matrixWorldAutoUpdate` functionality.

If you're wondering why they're doing this, there are a few discussions on Github worth checking out:

- [Why are you using "super-three"](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4898)
- [Changing A-Frame's THREE relationship](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4806)

Edit:

Noticed you already asked the question in the Github issue. Answer from [Vincent Fretin](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4898#issuecomment-1272478773):

> @flankechen The feature you're talking about was merged in three r144,
> so it's not in aframe 1.3.0 that uses three r137. Aframe master is
> currently using r144 via super-three fork that add some features back,
> see the 8 latest commit in the branch
> https://github.com/supermedium/three.js/commits/super-r144 You
> currently need to do your own build from master, the bot is down.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I get some more knowledge of their relations.